# Endless scroll function with adding same page

Tags: jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll

I would need an endless scroll function for a webpage. If the page gets scrolled to the bottom, the same page should be added without reloading the content.

Here would be a beginning of the code:

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

I would be so thankful for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just copy the contents of `body` and append it where your `alert` call is.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  var contents = $("body").html();

  $(window).scroll(function() {   
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
         $("body").append(contents);
     }
  });

})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hqLdowk/)

Worth pointing out, that I'd not leave this inside the body tags, but rather at the bottom of head, as duplicating the body element will result in the multiple instances of the script running.